# jScrollPane not working with jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jscrollpane

I use jScrollPane, and it works fine, but not when I use the load function in jQuery.

If I have one div that loads content with `overflow:auto`, and when the div is loaded, the content is different, the jScrollPane does not show the scrollbar.

For jQuery load I use this:

```
function infor(id) { 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#web_loader_text_content").show(2000);
        $("#web_loader_text_content").load("indexer_data.php?id="+id);
    }); 
}
```

I call for load contents in a div with links:

```
<div class="web_botones" id="b1" onclick="infor('houses1');"></div>
<div class="web_botones" id="b2" onclick="infor('houses2');"></div>
<div class="web_botones" id="b3" onclick="infor('houses3');"></div>
```

And the problem comes here:

```
$(function() { 
   $('#web_loader_text_content').jScrollPane();
});
```

The problem is that I have different contents with different sizes, and the scrollbars don't show.

Comment: You're putting `$(document).ready()` within a function, which I'm assuming you're not calling onLoad.

Comment: Yes i call and the problem no this you must know this plugin for solve this issue , thank´s , regards

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove the document.ready function from within the function you are calling:

And use:

```
autoReinitialise: true
```

in your jscrollpane initialize function. This property will reinitialize your jscrollpane and you dont have to worry about the loading data.